# What verb describes divisive behavior?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, morphology

I can't find a proper verb corresponding to the adjective *divisive*. If a person is divisive, then can I also say that they "divide other people apart"? Is there a verb for *divisive*?

Comment: I can't provide you with an exact answer, but judging on the handful of dictionaries I searched, the only thing close to a verb is its adverb "divisively".

Comment: _Assassinate_? Or is that just subtraction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Upset** would be the normal word to use. Otherwise

**Disrupt**      [(Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disrupt) has a rather narrow view)

> b :  to throw into disorder "agitators trying to disrupt the meeting"

Sociologists also use:
alienate, antagonise, upset, dissaffect. estrange.

Answer (score 0):

> From the Oxford dictionary
>
> **[Rift](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/rift#rift__6)** - *verb*: (usually as adjective rifted) Tear or force (something) apart

Comment: Also the verb *rive*, with past *rived* and past participle *riven*.

Comment: @tchrist, *cleave* may be the more modern verb?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why *divide* doesn't pass muster-- yes, you can say "divides others"-- but when it comes to relationships between people, there's:

[***sunder***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sunder) -

> to split apart (an organization, two people, etc.) especially in a violent way

... which is [most commonly seen](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sunder%2C+asunder&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csunder%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Casunder%3B%2Cc0) in the word *asunder*-- "tear asunder"-- because sunder is such a rare verb.  (Also *sundry*, so the root is still alive)

There is also *cleave*, but sunder has specific connotations for interpersonal relationships.

For verbs with adjectives, there's *sows discord, drives apart, creates rifts,* etc, but *sunder* is closest to what you want, albeit archaic.